# In Vue, there a memory/performance benefit to importing a collection of modals as a component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm creating an SPA using Vue.  One of my pages contains 17 different modals.  Some of the modals are relatively straightforward, while others have items which are hidden/not hidden  depending on different conditions.  I'd like to start refactoring my code by converting all of the basic text ones to a component:

```
<MyModalComponent :text="someText" :modal-id="someModalId"/>
```

and this will clean up some of my code.  I then started thinking that I can even just move the majority of the modals into a separate component (even the more complex ones), which would be a component which contains almost all of the modals.  Then, from the parent modal, I can just use:

```
this.$bvModal.show('some-id-of-some-modal')
```

to render it as needed.  This will definitely have the benefit of cleaning the page up.  My question is whether this method of importing all of the modals would also provide memory and/or performance benefits.

Comment: This totally depends on your implementations. If it wasn't really bad before then there are no performance benefits. There can be design benefits because you're able to manage them in a centralized way

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by it depends on my implementations?  Anything specific to be wary of?

Comment: You may be aware of memory leaks in such places, but nothing more specific.